# How to recover data from Intel SSD 320 Series

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, firmware

I have an Intel SSD 320 Series 600GB. A few days ago, my system froze because of some irrelevant failure and I had to force the computer to turn off. When I attempted to reboot the computer, my SSD no longer had any data on it. On further analysis, it was actually reporting itself as a 8 MB unit with no data or partitions.

I started doing some research and I found out that the 320 Series SSDs from Intel have a firmware bug that can render them bricked to an 8MB unit when some circumstances occur, like an unexpected power failure. The only solution I could find to ONLY recover the unit, was to erase the unit following the [instructions found here](http://www.tested.com/forums/pc-and-mac/44240-huge-bug-in-intel-ssds-complete-recovery-information-here/).

As for the data, no one seems to know of a way to recover it. Intel recommends a few companies that charge between $1,000 to $10,000 but offers no solution at all for their bug's consequences. I'm not saying my data is not worth that, but I simply don't have that kind of money right now. I have backups from about 1 month ago, but this month I had a lot of work I **really** want to recover.

I have tried with several programs (GetDataBack, RTT Studio, tools provided by other data recovery companies, etc.) but none of them can find a single file or folder after a 2 hours scan.

Can you think of a way to recover my data? I really hope you do. :-(

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is this a server or a PC?

Comment: It's a server board (dual hexacore Xeons) used as a workstation with Windows 7 x64).

Comment: Unfortunately, the adage of "Any data stored in less than 3 distinct locations ought to be considered temporary" still hasn't persuaded people to have reliable backup strategies… Drives die, bugs or no bugs. They rarely warn you.

Comment: Recovery software is recovery software. I would like to add those companies could have helped BEFORE you erased the data

Answer (score 0):

Try [UFS Explorer...](http://www.ufsexplorer.com) just in case before you reformat anything. Can you take a DD image of the device to another disk?

If your device is faulty, that's a *really* unfortunate bug.

https://gillware.com says they can help recover this, but you know that this is *really* a case of not having reliable backups. Best of luck.